# Specify both ordering indexes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a materialized view that has several columns of my most queried data.  Each column is used in where clasuses and each column is used for ordering ascending and descending nulls last.

I initially just declared a multicolumn index with all columns listed on the index but then I noticed any queries that included an orderby were very slow.

What is the right was to declare the indexes on this table?

Should I do it like this:

```
create index idx_table_search_group 
  on search_table (column1, column1 asc, column1 desc nulls last, column2, column2 asc, column2 desc nulls last, ... etc);
```

I am not sure if this is too much and I don't have to declare 3 indexes for each column or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad news is you need to declare separate indexes for each column. There's no way around this since you will need to order by any of those columns and -- when that happens -- that column needs to be first in the index position. This is to ensure the SQL optimizer uses an Index Range Scan.

The good news is you need only one for each column. PostgreSQL is capable of using each index in forward and reverse order.

I'm not sure if you need to create secondary ones for `NULLS LAST`. You'll need to test that.

Comment: ahh ok, so I create a index for every column instead of a multicolumn index right?

Comment: Yes, if you have 10 columns, then create 10 indexes. Multi-column indexes are useful or queries that meet that exact criteria.